# How to align divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set these divs to align like this:

[image]

but they end up either overlapping eachother (.title takes full width of container) or underneath eachother. Ideas?

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
}
.pic{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.title{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pic"><img src="..."></div>
    <div class="title"><p>title</p></div>
    <div class="content"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mmb84836/

Comment: Can you create a demo of your code using http://jsfiddle.net/ and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: I'd usually use two container divs, one for left and one for right set as inline-blocks. Then put the image inside the left one, and the title, content and footer inside the right one

Comment: How wide do you want the `.pic` element to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### As per the Best Practice:

Put Pic in one Box and the other three Boxes on right in one Box and use "**`float:left`** or `**display:inline-block**`for those.

Here is the code for the same:

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftBox">
        <div class="pic">pic</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightBox">
        <div class="title">title</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.wrapper {
    display: block; /*Default Property - You Can Remove Also*/
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
}
.leftBox {
    float:left;
    width :20%;
    height:100%
}
.rightBox {
    width :79.5%;
    float:left;
     height:100%
}
.pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
```

### Here is the Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7xLyc3q1/

Comment: That saved me an answer :P That's pretty much what I meant

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of answers here, but none of them explain what is actually happening here. When using `float`, there's something important you need to understand: floated elements are lifted out of the box model and have effectively zero width and height as far as other elements are concerned. There is a workaround for this: by specifying `overflow:hidden` in the **parent** element, floated elements will no longer "collapse".

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yw8bmm9k/) that demonstrates this. Notice that the title, content, and footer have a `width:100%`, and they're only filling the space that is remaining for them -- this is probably what you'd expect to happen. Notice also that there was no need to float them to the right... they take the space that's left.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `float: right` to `.title`, `.content`, and `.footer`.

Also it may be worth considering using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getboostrap.com). Both have grid systems so this would guarantee the divs would resize to fit any size screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="pic">pic</div>
<div class="other">oth1</div>
<div class="other">oth2</div>
<div class="other">oth3</div>
</div>

.wrap { width:100; height:200px; }
.pic { float:left; width:29%; height:100%; margin-right:1%; background-color:red; }
.other { float:left; width:70%; height:32%; margin-bottom:0.5%; background-color:green; }
```

and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t85kz39a/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it if you can specify a width for the image.  I assumed that the image would be 200px wide in this demo.

Try the following CSS:

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.pic{
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    border: 1px dashed  blue;
}
.pic img {
    display: block;
}
.title{
    width: auto;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.content{
    width: auto;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.footer{
    width: auto;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

The trick is to open up a space to place the image.  Add a 200px wide left padding to
the `.wrapper`.

The padding will force `.title`, `.content` and `.footer` to align 200px from the edge
of the wrapper.

For `.pic`, set the width to 200px (or smaller) and set the left margin to -200px to move
it into the padding area.

Finally, set the correct width for `.wrapper`, 600px.  The overall width of `.wrapper` 
will compute to 800px (600px width + 200px left padding - -200px left margin from the 
float).

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/mgg1stmc/

The main benefit of this approach is that you don't need to add any other wrapping
elements. (If you use floats, the extra wrappers are necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a much simpler css-only way without changing your HTML structure:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/bfhng3a9/

**All you need**:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.pic {
    float: left;
    width:20%;
}
.title, .content, .footer {
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and it is working according to your design.

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/0uqg782q/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="pic"><img src="..."/></div>
<div class="title"><p>Title</p></div>
<div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
<div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
 .wrapper{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    .pic{
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
    }
    .title{
        width: 650px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: green;
        position: relative;
        left: 350px;
        top:-16px;
    }
    .content{
        width: 650px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
        left: 350px;
        top: -22px;
    }
    .footer{
        width: 650px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: gold;
        position: relative;
        left: 350px;
        top: -28px;
    }
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]